# changing image according to the window width - responsive layout CSS? JQuery? Ajax?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Hi I'm trying to change an image as the window width changes without refreshing the page.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    if($(window).width() <= 600) {
        $('#img').attr('src','images/image.png');
        $('#img').css({"width": "50px"});
    };
});
```

This is the Jquery code that I've written but it only works when I refresh the page. how do I change the image when the width of window reaches 600px responsively?
I'm not sure if I should use css, ajax or jquery. thank you

Comment: use `$( window ).resize(function() {`

Comment: What about using media queries in your css instead?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This will work..

```
function adjustImage(){
if($(window).width() <= 600) {
        $('#img').attr('src','images/image.png');
        $('#img').css({"width": "50px"});
    };
}
$(document).ready(function(){

    adjustImage();
});

$( window ).resize(function() {
  adjustImage();
});
```

But we can do with CSS also as follow..

```
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
 #img{
   width:50px;
  }
}
```

Comment: thank you! this actually does work well but it seems like the div next to #img doesn't respond to the changed width. #img was originally 165px in width and when the width got changed to 50px, the div next to #img should fill up the gap when reducing the width of the window but it doesn't how do I fix that problem?

Comment: If you post your html structure may help me to provide solution.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40987622/changing-resizing-the-image-according-to-the-window-size here is the link to the new question

Answer (score 1):

The `@media` rule can be used for the desired effect.

Although I would add that **unless you are using different images**, it's **better to let `CSS` resize the image**. *It does it very well*.

*Open snippet in full-screen mode and resize your window from very small to big to see the effect*

```css
body {
  background: #111;
  margin: auto
}
@media screen and (max-width: 599px) {
  .simages {
    display: block
  }
  .bimages {
    display: none
  }
}
@media screen and (min-width: 600px) {
  .simages {
    display: none
  }
  .bimages {
    display: block
  }
}
```

```html
<body>
  <img class="simages" src="https://files.graphiq.com/stories/t2/The_16_Dogs_That_Won8217t_Make_You_Sneeze_2060_2848.jpg">
  <img class="bimages" src="https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/736x/f0/26/05/f0260599e1251c67eefca31c02a19a81.jpg">
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is always achieve with [css media query](https://developer.mozilla.org/zh-CN/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries)

Answer (score 0):

you can use css to do this. Give `max-width` : xxx px; to set maximum width of image  and `width` in percent. so it will automatically resize according to screen size.

```
img
{
   max-width : 550px;
   width : 75%; 
}
```

refer : http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_images.asp