# changing/ resizing the image according to the window size

Tags: jquery, html, css

I want to do something like YouTube header. When the width of the window reduces, its logo changes and gets rid of two of the menu icons on the right.

[codepen.io](https://codepen.io/hk0424/pen/GNxXvQ)

```
function adjustImage(){
if($(window).width() <= 600) {
    $('#logoDiv').css({"width": "30px", "float": "right"}); }

if($(window).width() > 600) {
    $('#logoDiv').css({"width": "165px", "backgroundColor": "red"});    }
}
--this is just a part of the code from the link--
```

please follow the link to see the code that I've written. It also seems like JQuery code is not working and I have no idea why

Comment: You need to add jquery as an external source to codepen for your code to work. Also for your `if($(window).width() > 600)` case, you need to add `"float":""` to reset the `"float":"right"` inline css that was added when resizing downwards.

Comment: why don't you use `bootstrap` [basic tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/default.asp)

Comment: you can do it with pure css

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Jquery way:-**

this can be achieved easily in media query in `CSS` itself, but it seems you need in jquery way. so answering in jquery way

add separate class for both widths and  toggle between these classes while resize by like  `$('#logoDiv').removeClass("desktop");  $('#logoDiv').addClass("mobile");`

[Check this fiddle](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/zoWmPE)

**Pure CSS way:-**

this can be achieved easily in media query in css itself

[Check this fiddle](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/BQrqra)

Answer (score 0):

for doing this you can use [media queries](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp) in css
for an example

```
headers{
  width:100%
}
.sidemenu{
  width:100px;
  float:right;
}
.logo{
  width:100px;
  float:left;
}

/* Your styles for small screen */
@media only screen and (max-width: 500px) {
  .logo{
    width:50px; 
  }
  .sidemenu{
    display:none;
  }
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/9h5smzuh/

Answer (score 0):

Don't need javascript ... can accomplish it with css

MENU1
      MENU2

```
#container {
  margin:0 auto;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    padding: 7px 5px 7px 5px;
    max-width: 1250px;
    height: 30px;
    border: 1px solid green;
  text-align: center;
}


#logoDiv{
    float:left;
    margin: 0;
    width: 165px;
    height: 30px;
  background-color: red;
}


#middleDiv {
  display: inline-block;
    margin:0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 35%;
    height: 30px;
    border: 1px solid blue;
}

#md{
    margin:0;
    height: 25px;
    padding-top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    border: 1px solid red;
}

.rightDiv {
  float:right;
    margin-left: 5px;
  width: 60px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

@media (max-width: 600px){
  #logoDiv{
    width: 30px;
    float: right;
    background-color: blue;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The bets way to achieve your requirement will be using **media queries**, rather than using `jQuery`. Media query itself provide best methods to adjust the screen representations so that you wont need to go for `jQuery` or `javascript`.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <style>
        #container {
            margin: 0 auto;
            margin-bottom: 10px;
            padding: 7px 5px 7px 5px;
            max-width: 1250px;
            height: 30px;
            border: 1px solid green;
            text-align: center;
        }
        
        #logoDiv {
            float: left;
            margin: 0;
            width: 165px;
            height: 30px;
            background-color: red;
        }
        
        #middleDiv {
            display: inline-block;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            width: 35%;
            height: 30px;
            border: 1px solid blue;
        }
        
        #md {
            margin: 0;
            height: 25px;
            padding-top: 0;
            width: 100%;
            border: 1px solid red;
        }
        
        .rightDiv {
            float: right;
            margin-left: 5px;
            width: 60px;
            border: 1px solid red;
        }
        
        @media (max-width: 600px) {
            #logoDiv {
                width: 30px;
                float: right;
                background-color: blue;
            }
            
            .rightDiv {
                display: none;
            }
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="container">

        <div id="logoDiv"></div>

        <div id="middleDiv">
            <input id="md" type="text">
        </div>

        <div class="rightDiv">MENU1</div>
        <div class="rightDiv">MENU2</div>
        <div class="rightDiv">MENU3</div>

    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

What you want to do is just put your requires styles inside

```
@media (max-width: 600px) {

}
```

This will be triggered when the size of your screen goes below 600px. I have added some sample code that I came to understand from your requirement. Look more about media queries [here](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp).